# Using author.dll with the Call HTTP Web Service action in SharePoint Online

Tags: web-services, designer-workflow

Has anyone been able to use the SharePoint Designer "Call HTTP Web Service" action with the _vti_bin/author.dll methods?

In particular, I'd like to move documents and their version history from one library into a sub folder of another library.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need to use the author.dll to move files between libraries. This can be done via object model to.

In the blog post [Maintain file version history when moving/copying files between SharePoint sites](http://sharepointvenividivici.typepad.com/sharepoint-customization/2011/06/maintain-file-version-history-when-movingcopying-files-between-sharepoint-sites.html) you will find detailed information what you need to do. This also includes a code snippet you can use.

**Update**

In Office 365 you can create a sand box solution that uses the server side code because all the required code is available. The code from the Article can also be rewritten to support client object model. If you don't like to execute it directly in Office 365. Please take a look at [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file_methods.aspx) or [Microsft.SharePoint.Client.FileVersionCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.fileversioncollection.aspx).

Author.dll is more likely to be used only by SharePoint Designer.

Comment: Thanks Stefan - I'm looking at ways to achieve this on an Office 365 environment, so the object model is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

I use the Web Request action with Nintex Worflow.

Take a look at this:
http://www.vadimtabakman.com/nintex-workflow-move-documents-and-preserve-version-history.aspx

URL:

```
(Your web URL)/_vti_bin/_vti_aut/author.dll
Method: POST
Content Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Header Name: X-Vermeer-Content-Type
Header Value: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Code:

```
method=move+document:14.0.2.5420&service_name=/&oldUrl=(Your source path and filename)&newUrl=(Your destination path and filename)&url_list=[]&rename_option=findbacklinks&put_option=overwrite,migrationsemantics
```

Comment: Thanks Robert. I don't have Nintex Workflow in this environment, as it is Office 365. I'm trying to work out how to invoke Author.dll from the "Call HTTP Web Service" action in SharePoint Designer 2013. The parameters available are:  
  
Address: http://intranet/_vti_bin/_vti_aut/author.dll  
RequestType: HTTP Post  
RequestHeaders: Dictionary variable  
RequestContent: Dictionary variable  
ResponseContent:  Dictionary variable  
ResponseHeaders:  Dictionary variable  
ResponseStatusCode: string variable

Comment: in my Nintex Workflow for Office 365 I have AppStep containging a Call HTTP Web Service with dictRequestContent var : key= method, value =                               copy+document:15.0.0.4420&service_name=/&oldUrl=https://tenant.sharepoint.com/teamsite/Source Library/MyDoc.doc&newUrl=https://tenant.sharepoint.com/teamsite/Dest Library/MyDoc.doc   I am getting unauthorised in the response code ;-(  does this look correct anyone

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to do it with the REST service and 2013 workflow's Call HTTP Webservice.

http://johnliu.net/blog/2014/2/19/using-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow-to-copy-file-via-res.html

Haven't succeeded yet with author.dll